# Using Right-Hand Rule for a Current Running in a Loop

Tags: electromagnetism

[image: Here is the problem]

Hello. Using the right hand rule, shouldn't the magnetic force be going into the paper, since velocity is to the left and the force caused by centripetal acceleration is downward? The answer key says that the answer is C. How is it not D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I remembered the rule for how magnetic fields around wires work is the following. Take your right hand, and point your thumb in such a way so that it points in the same direction as the current, and curl the rest of your fingers.

[image]

The direction your fingers curl represents the direction of the magnetic field. So, when you use this rule, you'd see that no matter what part of the loop you use the right hand rule on, your fingers will be pointing towards you to the left of the current, which tells you the answer should be **out of the page**.